# What is the shortest and most effecient way to get the result for this program?

Tags: c++

This is the code:
is there a way to make this more efficient?
efficiency is to make it shorter and faster in my case

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
 int i, n, a[10], b[10];
 cin >> n;

 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
 {
  cin >> a[i] >> b[i];
 }

 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
 {
  if (a[i] > b[i])
  cout << "Participant 1 wins\n";
  else
  cout << "Participant 2 wins\n";
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're looking for an efficient result, please give context as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your code doesn't compile in most machines. Reason? `cout` and `cin` are parts of the Standard namespace `std`, which means that you cannot access them unless you use the appropriate commands. This can be done in two ways:

- Write `std::cout` instead of `cout`. This tells the compiler that you want to access the object `cout`, which is a part of the standard namespace
- Before the main body, write `using namespace std;`. This will offer you direct access to everything that belongs to the standard namespace, and is found in the headers you included.

Now let's talk about efficiency:

- You don't have to use arrays. You can process the data while you read it from the standard input. 
  This will reduce the space complexity from `O(N)` to `O(1)`. In other words, you will have constant space.
- If you want your code to execute much faster, and you are familiar with C programming language, you can use C-style input and output. It less readable, but much more efficient and fast, as it is implemented in assembly (machine language).
- You can reduce the length of your code by using inline `if-else` statement. Please note that this is **not** a good practice, as it makes your code **very** difficult to read.

Putting all together:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
  int i, n, a, b;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("Participant %d wins\n", (a > b) ? 1 : 2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```